# How to Convert Unicode Characters to HTML Encoding C++?

Tags: html, c++, encoding

I need your help.. How to convert unicode characters like this in C++

```
Thére Àre sôme spëcial charâcters ïn thìs têxt
عربى
```

to HTML encoding like this ?

```
Th&eacute;re &Agrave;re s&ocirc;me sp&euml;cial char&acirc;cters &iuml;n th&igrave;s t&ecirc;xt
&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1609;
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated 
Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks Kevin but this isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can find a third-party API to handle this for you, you will likely have to code it yourself manually:

1. Convert the input string data to codepoint values (ie, to UTF-32).
2. For each codepoint value:

   a. if it is in the ASCII visual range (U+0009, U+000A, U+000D, and U+0020 through U+007E), store/display the value as-is as an 8bit ASCII character.

   b. otherwise, check if there is an available entity name associated with the codepoint (see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html), [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/syntax.html#named-character-references), [this](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) and [this](http://entitycode.com)) and if so then store/display that name in `&name;` format.

   c. otherwise, store/display the codepoint value in `&#XXXX;` format, where `XXXX` is the numeric value of the codepoint.

Comment: Thank you so much Remy Lebeau :)